# Retina MacBook Air: External Monitor lag issue

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, 4k

I have a new 2018 Retina MacBook Air, 1.6Ghz i5, 16GB memory, Intel UHD Graphics 617 1536 MB. I am connecting this to an external monitor, a [Dell P2415Q](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/accessories/apd/210-agnk), using an HDMI cable and a [Targus DOCK412USZ](https://us.targus.com/products/usb-c-travel-dock-with-power-pass-through-dock412usz)

My issue is that the output on the external display is very laggy and noticeably slower. The screen also flickers occasionally.

I have tried using a different resolution on the external monitor, which did not solve my problems. I've also tried using a DisplayPort to Thunderbolt cable, which also did not solve my problem.

What can be done to resolve the lag issue?